# Taking the mean of 10000 replications of random sampling for each row

Tags: r

I did a replication 10000 times where I took a random sample from a list of ID's and then paired them with another list of IDs. After that I added a colomn that gives the relatedness of pair to each other. Then I took thee mean of the relatedness for each set of random sampling. So I end up with 10000 values which represent the mean of the relatedness for each set of random sampling. However, I want to instead take the mean of the relatedness of first row for all the 10000 sets of random sampling.

An example of what I want:

Lets say I have 10000 sets of 3 random pairings.

```
Set 1
     female_ID male_ID relatedness
  0  12-34     23-65   0.034
  1  44-62     56-24   0.56
  2  76-11     34-22   0.044

Set 2
     female_ID male_ID relatedness
  0  98-54     53-12   0.022
  1  22-43     13-99   0.065
  2  09-22     65-22   0.12

etc...
```

I want the mean of the rows for relatedness of each set, so I want a list of 3   values: 0.028 (mean of 0.034 and 0.022), 0.3125 (mean of 0.56 and 0.065), 0.082 (mean of 0.044 and 0.12), except it would be the mean across 10000 sets, and not just 2.

Here's my code so far:

```
    mean_rel <- replicate(10000, {
       random_mal <- sample(list_of_males, 78, replace=TRUE)
       random_pair <- cbind(list_of_females, random_mal)
       random_pair <- data.frame(random_pair)
       random_pair$pair <- with(random_pair, paste(list_of_females, random_mal, sep = " "))
       typeA <- genome$rel[match(random_pair$pair, genome_year$pair1)]
       typeB <- genome$rel[match(random_pair$pair, genome_year$pair2)]
       random_pair$relatedness <- ifelse(is.na(typeA), typeB, typeA)
       random_pair <- na.omit(random_pair)
       mean_random_pair_relatedness <- mean(random_pair$relatedness)
       mean_random_pair_relatedness
    })
```

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable, reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you add `simplify = FALSE` to your `replicate` after the between the closing `}` and `)`, then mean_rel will be output as a list.

```
   mean_rel <- replicate(10000, {
     random_mal <- sample(list_of_males, 78, replace=TRUE)
     random_pair <- cbind(list_of_females, random_mal)
     random_pair <- data.frame(random_pair)
     random_pair$pair <- with(random_pair, paste(list_of_females, random_mal, sep = " "))
     typeA <- genome$rel[match(random_pair$pair, genome_year$pair1)]
     typeB <- genome$rel[match(random_pair$pair, genome_year$pair2)]
     random_pair$relatedness <- ifelse(is.na(typeA), typeB, typeA)
     random_pair <- na.omit(random_pair)
     mean_random_pair_relatedness <- mean(random_pair$relatedness)
     mean_random_pair_relatedness
  }, simplify = FALSE)
```

From there, you can use `purrr` to add two classification columns and then can use `dplyr` for the rest. Here is how I did it:

```
library(tidyverse)
mean_rel <- purrr::map2(.x = mean_rel, .y = seq_along(mean_rel), 
                        function(x, y){
                          x %>%
                            mutate(set = paste0("set_", y)) %>%
                            # do this so the same row of each set can be 
                            # compared
                            rownames_to_column(var = "row_number")
})

mean_rel_comb <- mean_rel %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  mutate(relatedness = as.numeric(as.character(relatedness))) %>%
  group_by(row_number) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(relatedness))
```

Using your two datasets combined as a list gave me this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  row_number   mean
       <chr>  <dbl>
1          1 0.0280
2          2 0.3125
3          3 0.0820
```